# YUI3 Datasource to return custom Object

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

How can I get the YUI3 sendRequest applied to a Datasource to return predefined objects, instead of plain ones?

For example, I have this Base class with its methods:

```
function Student(id, name){
   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
}
Context.prototype.setId   = function(id){ this.id = id; };
Context.prototype.setName = function(name){ this.name = name; };
Context.prototype.getId   = function(){ return this.id; };
Context.prototype.getName = function(){ return this.name; };
```

And I have this code that retrieves data from an API, normalizes it and returns data as objects:

```
var studApiDataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({source: API_URL});

studApiDataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
  schema: {
    resultListLocator: "response.student",
    resultFields: ["id","name"]
  }
});

var myCallback = function(e) {
  Y.Array.each(e.response.results, function(stud){
    Y.log(stud.id+' '+stud.name);
  }
}

studApiDataSource.sendRequest({
  request: "?cmd=getStudents",
  callback: {
    success: myCallback,
    failure: function (e) { }
  }
});
```

The array of objects retrieved by studApiDataSource.sendRequest() and passed to myCallback are normal objects, with id and name properties. However, I want these to be Student objects, with their member functions too (getId, getName etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but you could do something like the following.

```
var studentJSON = "{\"id\": 17, \"name\":\"my name is\"}";
function Student(obj){
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.id = obj.id;
}
Student.prototype.setId   = function(id){ this.id = id; };
Student.prototype.setName = function(name){ this.name = name; };
Student.prototype.getId   = function(){ return this.id; };
Student.prototype.getName = function(){ return this.name; };

YUI().use('json-parse', 'json-stringify', function (Y) {

    try {

        var stud = new Student(Y.JSON.parse(studentJSON));
        alert(stud.getId());
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }

});
```